# SSH IdentitiesOnly=yes forwarding all my keys

Tags: ssh, public-key-encryption, ssh-agent

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my SSH config is forwarding the wrong key. I have two keys, we'll call them `home_rsa` and `work_rsa`. I have done the following:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/home_rsa
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/work_rsa
```

Here is my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host home
  ForwardAgent yes
  HostName home.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/home_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  User home

Host work
  ForwardAgent yes
  HostName work.com
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_rsa
  User work

Host bitbucket
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/home_rsa

Host bitbucket-work
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_rsa

Host bitbucket*
  HostName bitbucket.com
  User git
```

When I run the following…

```
ssh work
ssh git@bitbucket.org
```

…Bitbucket reports that I'm using my `home` user, though I'm clearly logged into my `work` server and should be forwarding my `work` key. If I add my SSH identities in the reverse order and run the same code above, Bitbucket reports I'm using my `work` user. Running `ssh-add -l` from my `work` server, I see that both SSH keys are being forwarded, but isn't that the job of `IdentitiesOnly yes`?

Really confused as to what's going on here.

Comment: No.  `IdentitiesOnly` controls what key is used for authentication, but does not affect the list of keys available in your agent.

Comment: Oh. Then is there a way to control which key(s) are made available in my agent on a per-server basis?

Comment: Not really, no.  I mean, you could hack up something with multiple local agents, but it probably wouldn't be pretty.

Comment: I said in another comment: "Bitbucket disallows using the same SSH key between Bitbucket accounts. I have a work account and a personal account. When I try to push/fetch/merge/etc., I want the remote server to be using the correct SSH key." Is there any [sane] way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Really confused as to what's going on here.

`ForwardAgent` option forwards the connection to your agent, with all the keys inside and does not forward your local `~/.ssh/config` to remote host. What you do on the `work` host is controlled by your configuration on that host.

What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: Bitbucket disallows using the same SSH key between Bitbucket accounts. I have a work account and a personal account. When I try to push/fetch/merge/etc., I want the remote server to be using the correct SSH key.

Comment: Yes, and I understand your answer. But you asked what I am trying to do with that. I am trying to push/fetch/merge/etc. on my remote server.

Comment: So then you need: 1) To create such configuration on the remote server (it might not work, since the keys are not local). 2) Differentiate between the keys in other way, for example by confirmation (`-c` switch to `ssh-add`). 3) Use different keys for connecting from that server.

Answer (score 5):

You need to update your ssh keys with their equivalent bitbucket account first at their website (work user with `work_rsa`, user with `user_rsa`). Then maybe this could help.

```
Host                bitbucket-work
HostName            bitbucket.org
IdentitiesOnly      yes
IdentityFile        ~/.ssh/work_rsa
User                work
```

Usage:

```
ssh bitbucket-work
```

[ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh)[bitbucket](/questions/tagged/bitbucket)

Answer (score 5):

As written in the accepted answer, selecting keys used for authentication is not related to what keys are forwarded. Separate ssh-agents are needed. Luckily that is easily configured.

From [ssh-agent (1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-agent) we can learn that it takes a `-a` option to specify *bind_address*, and [ssh_config (5)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ForwardAgent) tells that `ForwardAgent` can be set to what turns out to be the same value.

Prepare your agents:

```bash
eval `ssh-agent -a ~/.ssh/home.agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/home_rsa
eval `ssh-agent -a ~/.ssh/work.agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/work_rsa
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID
```

Configure your ssh:

```
Host work
    HostName      work.example.com
    ForwardAgent  ~/.ssh/work.agent
    IdentityAgent ~/.ssh/work.agent

Host home
    HostName      home.example.com
    ForwardAgent  ~/.ssh/home.agent
    IdentityAgent ~/.ssh/home.agent
```

That should completely separate home and work keys. Setting `IdentityAgent` to a different value than `ForwardAgent` is left as an exercise for someone exposed to a threat level calling for such complexity.